# How to detect mesh advanced selection mode (new, extend, subtract, invert, intersect)

Tags: python, add-on

I'm coding an add-on to help me selecting faces of complex but regular meshes.

It would be useful to operate on current selection extending, subtracting (and so on) faces.

I'd like to use the already available UI buttons (the ones placed to the top-left of the 3D View editor), but I can't find how to detect the current selection mode.

Clicking on those buttons doesn't generate any trace message to the INFO panel, so I haven't got any idea of which bpy element to search to get this piece of information.